# Refactor Implicit Variable Assignment in Array to Explicit Assignment Outside of Array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, coderush

I have a code block that is implicitly adding variables to an array, i.e.

`context.People.Add(
    new Person { Name = "Joe", Age = 45 },
    new Person { Name = "Alicia", Age = 33 } );`

What I need is for the variables to be accessible outside of the code block, i.e.

```
var personJoe = new Person { Name = "Joe", Age = 45 };
var personAlicia = new Person { Name = "Alicia", Age = 33 };
context.People.Add(personJoe, personAlicia);
```

This way I can access the person variables when I need to make an assignment to another entity that has a relationship with person.

My question is, what is the easiest way to perform this refactoring? I understand I can copy/paste, but the block I have is approximately 200 lines long, and I have found myself needing this type of re-factoring often. If at all possible, I would like to avoid paid solutions (ReSharper), but if this is the only way to get this process automated, I will seriously consider it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Updated the question to be more explicit about what I am asking for.

Comment: Is *context* the DbContext in EntityFramework?

Comment: It is in my specific context, but that's not important. I will change the question to remove the Entity Framework related code.

Comment: I'm asking because, it could be helpful if you can change the *Add* implementation to return the added entities, so `var people = context.People.Add(..., ...);`

Comment: I see. I actually misused the Add method in this example, I am using AddOrUpdate and just changed it to Add in the question in order to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me this is simply an Introduce Variable refactoring.  Visual Studio doesn't have this refactoring built in; but may other add-ons do.  If you don't want a paid solution, then the refactoring consists of copy/paste then adding a variable and using it.

To do this in Resharper (with the Visual Studio keyboard scheme), simple select where you instantiate the Person (e.g. `new Person { Name = "Alicia", Age = 33 }`) and press Ctrl+R,V.

Comment: Do you know which of the paid solutions actually offer this refactoring? I looked at Resharper's website, but it wasn't clear to me if they offer this as an option.

Comment: Resharper has it (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Introduce_Variable.html, or see edit) as well as CodeRush (Although they call it "Introduce Result Variable": 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument2902 or Introduce Local: https://documentation.devexpress.com/CodeRush/CustomDocument1506.aspx)

Comment: Telerik's JustCode has it as well: http://www.telerik.com/help/justcode/refactorings-introduce-variable.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It would be nice to be able to do it en masse, but this will have to do. Thanks Peter

Comment: I had that same idea, Hadi Hariri added it as a suggestion for Resharper: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-200132

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this CodeRush plugin. (It took about 20-30 minutes :) ) I think it does what you're looking for.

[image: Introduce Local (All arguments)]

If you've got CodeRush installed you can [Download it here](https://github.com/RoryBecker/CR_IntroduceLocalAllArguments/releases/tag/v1.0)

Comment: Omg... I don't have CodeRush but that is exactly what I was looking for. Nice work

Comment: Adding features to CodeRush is really easy when you know how :)

See http://rorybecker.github.io/CodeRushPlugins/

Comment: FWIW this refactoring plugin will also work within the CodeRush trial, available here -> https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/